# makefile is interpreted differently in Make-linux and Make MinGW

Tags: linux, makefile, mingw

In Make file we have:

```
TARGET = CAN_PWM_test
BUILD_DIR = build
```

`all: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).hex $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).bin`

Next

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c %.cpp Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@
```

and

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) Makefile
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    $(SZ) $@
```

in Linux i take message:

`>make: *** No rule to make target 'build/main.o', needed by 'build/CAN_PWM_test.elf'.  Stop.`

But in windows with MinGW that works.
What I did wrong?

(full project on the github: [Link](https://github.com/avagro/CANtestSTM32f303) )

in Makefile we have windows-like GCCPATH, for linux I commented it.
But that wasn`t helped.

```
> make -v 
GNU Make 4.4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Please don't do that "we have", "next", "and". Post a complete minimal makefile. What is `OBJECTS`?

Answer (score 0):

This rule ...

> ```
> $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c %.cpp Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
>         $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@
> ```

... describes how to build an object file from both a corresponding .c file and a corresponding .cpp file, *together*.  Though it lies about that, because in fact it uses only the .c file.  This rule does not apply for building an object file for which there is not both a corresponding .c file and a corresponding .cpp file.

> in Linux i take message:
>
> `>make: *** No rule to make target 'build/main.o', needed by 'build/CAN_PWM_test.elf'.  Stop.`

That seems likely.

> But in windows with MinGW that works.

I do not believe you.  Some aspect of the project is different between the two sides -- maybe the makefile, maybe the contents of the source directory, maybe both.  It's not the same "that".

> What I did wrong?

You wrote a pattern rule with incorrect prerequisites.  If you have a mixture of C and C++ sources then you should have separate rules for the two.  That would also afford you the opportunity to have different *recipes* for those rules, which is usually advisable anyway.

Comment: Just to follow up on John's answer: a pattern rule only matches if ALL the prerequisites either exist or can be built by make.  By having both `%.c %.cpp` listed as prerequisites this pattern rule will only match to build a file like `foo.o` if **BOTH** the source files `foo.c` **AND** `foo.cpp` exist or can be built.  Since I'd say that's very rare, then mostly this pattern rule is useless and won't be used to build anything.

Answer (score 0):

@John, thanks for the clarification about a pattern rule, I wasn't known how dos it works.

You right about `I do not believe you` : that rule is not works, but MinGW answered different:

```
"C:/Program Files/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/bin"/arm-none-eabi-gcc -x assembler-with-cpp -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F303xC -IInc -IDrivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IDrivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F3xx/Include -IDrivers/CMSIS/Include -Og -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -IDrivers -IDrivers/tm1638-library Drivers/WProgram.cpp Drivers/tm1638-library/TM1638.cpp  -x c++ -MMD -MP -MF"build/startup_stm32f303xc.d" startup_stm32f303xc.s -o build/startup_stm32f303xc.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: fatal error: cannot specify '-o' with '-c', '-S' or '-E' with multiple files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [build/startup_stm32f303xc.o] ������ 1
```

The problem is that the project contains modules in C and C++ and they need to be built together.

As I understand from your answer: I need to make 2 different rules for assembling .o from .c and .o from .cpp

I will try. Thanks for help!